# Can we add Azure AD accounts instead of the Guest accounts?

Tags: sharepoint-online, azure, licensing

Suppose we have

- 100 employess from an external vendor. They need access to our SharePoint Online site to get access to some documents.
- These users don't need Teams, Word, mailboxes etc from Microsoft 365. Just a site access. They also don't have corporate M365 licenses.
- We have 0 licenses left in our Microsoft 365 subscription.
- We need to invite a lot of external users without creating a ton of mail boxes on outlook.com/hotmail
- We don't want ask these external users to create Microsoft accounts (because it's not great user experience and very buggy. On top of it, many external users fail to do it even with a good visual manual.

Can we create 100 users using Azure AD, via Azure Portal (not Microsoft 365 Tenant admin!) and just add these 100 users to the SharePoint site? I've just checked. **Technically it works.** The end result is identical to inviting the external guests. The second option is a lot less paintful though.

**Now the question is this:** Is it really supported by Microsoft? Is not considered a license violation?

We really want to use this approach since we can create many accounts at once and just send login/password to the users and all we want the users to do is just access the SharePoint site.

**Update:**

- I know that users, created in our own AD are not considered external.
- Even if I don't apply the licenses it just works.
- I could not find any written information specifically prohibiting scenario

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a technical license violation. Yes, SharePoint Online licensing is loosely or outright not enforced, but if Microsoft were to ask or audit you, you would be responsible for acquiring those additional licenses.

Comment: Is there a text where it's explicitly said? I find it hard to believe that Microsoft could not enforce this polocy if this scenarion is a violation

Comment: What you're asking is "What is the point of SharePoint Online licensing". The point is that you must license all of your users. If you need further information on Microsoft licensing, contact Microsoft Licensing directly as they are fully aware of licensing requirements. And no, enforcement is not there for SPO.

Comment: Thank you, Trevor. Unfortunately I have to agree with you here. Looks like there are quite a few people saying that it's not a supported scenario. That's such a shame though!

Answer (score 0):

Check out this link: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Manage-external-sharing-for-your-SharePoint-Online-environment-c8a462eb-0723-4b0b-8d0a-70feafe4be85
It seems you can invite external users to collaborate on your Sharepoint Online without the need to assigning them your O365 licenses. Definitely worth considering!

Comment: This is a question specifically about Azure AD accounts. Everyone knows you can invite external users for free using their private emails. I was asking about Azure AD because it's a very nice option since you can create a bulk of accounts with passwords, whereas, when you invite, let's say 100 external users, super messy. It's super-hard to control true external users if they are not part of your AD